# contenteditable in chrome and safari replaces css classes and rules with inline style

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, contenteditable

I’m writing a simple wysiwyg editor with the ability to apply css classes to text, I have encountered the following problem in chrome and safari:

In a contenteditale area, if you manually add a css class to an element, or have a css rule for h1 (for example) with ‘display: inline’. After some operations, like delete or copy/cut +paste you get the style as inline style and lose all the attributes on the elements.
I guess that the browser sets only the relevant computed style on the element.
Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

```
<span class="red">aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbb</span>
```

=>

```
<span class="Apple-style-span" style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); font-size:     20px;">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</span>
```

•   This example is with ‘styleWithCss’

Comment: `contenteditale` is a real mess, as it evolved over time without any kind of specification, on how it should behave, and does to many things on its own without one having control over it. the reason is likely because copy and past can change the styling if pasted at a different place as different rules can apply. However, that's often what you want as a default for a wysiwyg. That's why so less complete wysiwyg editors exists, and most of the other wysiwyg editors get stuck at some point in devleopment.

Comment: To get a reliable wysiwyg editor you  end up on one of the following things: **1.** Do all of the text rendering and manipulation yourself in a canvas (like google docs does) **2.** fixing all those "glitches" after insert  (like imho TinyMCE and CKEditor 3 does) resulting in a large portion of the editor code being then about that **3.** Implement the whole editor as a virtual DOM, use the input information you get from `contenteditable` to update the virtual DOM and then update the real content editable based on your virtual DOM (like CKEditor 4 does)

Answer (score 0):

in 2011 this was a "feature" of WebKit. and I believe it still is...

But, there seems to be a solution, though I didn't dive in. take a look at:
https://www.w3.org/TR/input-events/

https://webkit.org/blog/7358/enhanced-editing-with-input-events/